# Is there relationship between valency of graph $X$ and Number of connection set $C$?

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $C$ be a subset of $G$ that is closed under taking inverses and does not contain the identity. Then the Cayley graph $X=Cay(G, C)$ is the graph with vertex set $G$ and edge set $$ E(Cay(G, C))=\{ gh \ | \ hg^{-1}\in C\}.$$
We say that $C$ is connection set.

> Is there relationship between valency of Cayley graph $X$ and number of connection set $C$?

Comment: what is valency of a graph? what is connection set?

Comment: Connection set is a subset $C$ of $G$ that is closed under taking inverses and does not contain the identity and any Cayley graph $X$ is $k$-regular then $k$ is valency of any vertex in $X$ so is valency of $X$.